# Biggest number divisible by $99$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, contest-math

John has $1012$ stickers on which the numbers $1000,1001,\cdots,2010,2011$ are written.He wants to put them(not necessarily all) in a row so that he gets the biggest number which is divisible by 99(putting $k$ stickers he gets a $4k$-digit number).

My attempt is since $10^4\equiv 1\pmod{99}$ then we can look the number as a sum of the $4$ digit numbers.Since sum of all the remainders $\pmod{9}$ is divisible by $9$ we can see that the sum of all the numbers is just equal to $2008+2009+2010+2011\equiv 1\pmod{9}$ and doing that $\mod{11}$ we get that it's equal to $1000+2003+2004+\cdots+2010+2011\equiv 0\pmod{11}$
So this means that our number can't be $4048$-digit number but it can be a $4044$-digit number which you can get without using the smallest number that is divisible by $11$ and gives remainder $1$ $\pmod{11}$ which is $1045$ so our number is $\overline{2011\cdots10461044\cdots10011000}$
Am I correct?

Comment: I'm not following you all the way through.  (I'm not saying your reasoning is wrong, just that I'm not following.)  I see the argument in the first sentence, but the "sum of all the remainders mod $9$" part is where I start getting lost.  Maybe too many calculations omitted?  Also, $2012$ shouldn't be at the front of your answer.

Comment: Well $1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9=45\equiv 0\pmod{9}$ hence summing $1000,1001\cdots 1008,1009$ is equal to $0\pmod{9}$,and basically any sum of $9$ consecutive numbers which start from $1\pmod{9}$ is divisible by $9$,which means that sum of the numbers from $1000$ to $2007$ is divisible by $9$.Why shouldn't 2012 be in front?

Comment: Ahh, gotcha on the mod $9$ part.  As for the $2012$, from the problem statement your stickers only go up to $2011$.

Comment: 7 mod9 , 2 mod11. 79 mod 99. Remove 1069.